# Finding a decider

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Let $L\in R, L_2\in RE$ and $n\in N$.
Define $L_n=${$w|w\in L \vee (w\in L_2 \wedge |w|\leq )$}
Find a decider for $L_n$

For the right hand side, I thought I could check the length of  and then simulate the recognizer that recognizes $L_2$ until it accepts. I don't know how many steps it'll take the machine to halt and accept, and it might also never halt.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: All finite languages are decidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to construct the machine, you only have to show one exists. The language $\{w\in L_2 \mid |w|\le n\}$ is finite, even if we do not know any of its elements.

Comment: How can I tell what strings are in the language, if I can't simulate $L_2$ (because I might go into an infinite loop)?

Comment: You are right, you can't. The point is that you can show that new $L_n$ is recursive/decidable without actually constructing the decider. For the finite fragment of $L_2$ there exists a list of its elements, so there exists a decider for that finite language. Exists, but I cannot actually construct it.

Comment: Can I claim that $L_2$ is finite and therefore there exists a DFA so that $<L_{DFA},w>\in A_{DFA}$ and since $A_{DFA}$ is decidable, so does $L_2$?

Comment: Exactly. (And I add some characters here because there is a minimum for a comment)